# compare two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ipython

[image]

Need to compare two dictionaries help me out. Leave down the correct syntax if I doing it wrong, Thank you

Comment: Please paste the actual code next time.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please change the Kernel to `Python 2.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. In your case the `choice` is taken as dictionary 1 and `week` is taken as dictionary 2. `cmp` function is not defined in python 3 so you are getting an error . If you use same code in python 2 then your code will run without any error.

Here is the code in python 2.7:

```
>>> choice = {'fav': ['biryani', 'chow mein', 'tikka']}
>>> week = {'cook': ['rice', 'pulses', 'pualo', 'biryani']}
>>> cmp(choice, week)
1
```

Comment: Hi, is there an alternative method for dictionary in Python 3 or do we have to implement a Custom function for that purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.x, `cmp` is deprecated. You can use it in Python 2.7

Doing so in Python 2.7 gives the following result:

```
>>> choice = {'fav': ['biryani', 'chow mein', 'tikka']}
>>> week = {'cook': ['rice', 'pulses', 'pualo', 'biryani']}
>>> cmp(choice, week)
1
```